# Prevent replacements of emoticons in HTML-tags

Tags: php, regex, emoticons

I use a simple `str_replace`-function to replace some emoticons on my website…

```
<?php

$replace = array(
    ':)' => 'smile',
    ';)' => 'wink',
    …
);

$string = 'Lorem ipsum (&quot;dolor&quot;) sit amet! :)';

foreach($replace as $search => $replace) {
    $string = str_replace($search, '<img src="/img/'.$replace.'.png" alt="'.$search.'">', $string);
}

?>
```

The problem about this simple replacement is, that ";)" from the `&quot;`-tag would be replaced aswell and the HTML-code would be broken. Is there any way/workaround (a special regex i.e.) to solve this "problem"? Thanks! :)

Comment: Maybe add a space before `;)` ?

Comment: Or maybe word boundaries: `\b` (but you'd need a regex for that)

Comment: very simple add one space in search string like: `str_replace(" ".$search, ' <img src="/img/'.$replace.'.png" alt="'.$search.'">', $string);` and this will find the space before smiles. this is a trick  .

Comment: Good idea, but optimally I want to replace emoticons in strings like "Awesome;)" too (as I don't always know that posters use spaces in front of the emoticon).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to do this:

```
$replace = array(
    ' :)' => ' smile',
    ' ;)' => ' wink',
);
```

Basically only replace the emoticons if they are preceded with a space. If a user writes:

`Hello my name is John:)` - that is their mistake, not yours.

---

A second option would be to use [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) before replacing the emoticons.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace` with `\B` (non-word boundary)

```
$string = preg_replace("/\B".preg_quote($search)."\B/", '<img src="/img/'.$replace.'.png" alt="'.$search.'">', $string);
```

Tested

```
[root@srv ~]# php test.php
Lorem ipsum (&quot;dolor&quot;) sit amet! <img src="/img/smile.png" alt=":)">
```

Comment: you should preg_quote() the $search variable first

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$string = html_entity_decode($string);
```

before the replacement (the foreach), this way the `&quot;` would be read as actual quotes, and not being replaced. And you can use htmlentities() afterward to have the `&quot;'s` again if you are storing on database or something.

Comment: This would allow cross site scripting (`&lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;` would turn into `<script></script>`). And if I convert it back after the emoticon-replacement, the `<img>`-tags are converted too, so it would be useless in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is My second answer, you are right, in the end we would need to use regex.
Basically There's the `$negation` regex prepended to the escaped searches, I guess it can be optimized but for now it worked for me.

```
$smileys = array(
    ':)' => 'smile',
    ';)' => 'wink'
);

$string = 'Lorem ipsum (&quot;dolor&quot;) sit amet! :)';

$negation = '[^&\w*]'; // Here is the magic, this is the part that avoids the search to be preceded by &+characters
foreach($smileys as $icon => $name) {
  $replace[] = '<img src="/img/'.$name.'.png" alt="'.$icon.'">'; //we create an array with the corresponding replaces
  $search[] = '/'.$negation.preg_quote($icon).'/'; //Magic second part, preg_quote escapes the smileys to sarch for PCRE, we prepend the magical regex.
}

$string = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```